# homestead : serve command not working

Tags: homestead

i installed vagrant on my new machine and its not working. when i execute `serve domain path`, the output shows.

```
dos2unix: converting file /vagrant/scripts/serve-laravel.sh to Unix format ...
```

whereas in another system where the serve command works, when i type the same command it shows

```
dos2unix: converting file /vagrant/scripts/serve.sh to Unix format ...
nginx stop/waiting
nginx start/running, process 1960
php5-fpm stop/waiting
php5-fpm start/running, process 1975
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like serve functionality is removed in the newer vagrant, and that the preferred method these days is:

1. edit your Homestead.yaml file to map domains to paths
2. vagrant provision (from your homestead directory)